# how can I findAndModify one record in mongodb with golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, atomic, findandmodify

I want something like this:

1. find one record in mongo db `old_record`
2. update this record to `new_record`
3. return `old_record`

I write code like this:

```
ret = nil
// First, Find the obj
obj := &orm.QuerySetObj{}
err2 := this.querySetCollection.With(session).Find(objKey).One(obj)
if nil != err2 {
    this.logger.Println("Error find obj")
    return
}

ret = obj

// Then, update this obj
obj.updateTime = time.Now().Unix()
err3 := this.querySetCollection.With(session).Upsert(objKey, obj)
if nil != err3 {
    this.logger.Println("Error update obj")
    return
}

return
```

but, I think `find` and `update` should be an `atomic` operation, so my code is not safe.

how can I do this in an atomic operation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method here is [**`.Apply()`**](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.Apply) which takes a [Change](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Change) type and returns [ChangeInfo](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#ChangeInfo).

Direct example in the documentation:

```
change := mgo.Change{
        Update: bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"n": 1}},
        ReturnNew: false,
}
info, err = col.Find(M{"_id": id}).Apply(change, &doc)
fmt.Println(doc.N)
```

Where `doc` is document that is found, and it's state depending on the value of `ReturnNew` in the `Change` arguments, being `false` where you want the original document.

Basically all arguments are in the same form as with [`.findAndModify()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

Comment: actually I have found this answer before I ask, but I just find one record, I should replace `One(obj)` with `limit(1)`?

Comment: @roger That is not a `.findAndModify()`. That is called retriving the object then saving it back. `.findAndModify()` or `.Change()` in this case makes the modification directly on the server and either returns the updated object or original object. Just as stated here already.

Comment: @roger No the oposite. `.Apply()` with the `Change` set here **is atomic**, your code is not. That is the problem I am solving here. There is no `.One()` call. This "only" modifies one document at a time. This **is** the mgo version of `.findAndModify()`, which is the question you asked,

Comment: OK, now I just understand you meaning, you mean your code will **just find one and update exactly the one**, but I get another question, I want to `find and modify n records`, can I do this?

Comment: @roger That is what the `.findAndModify()` method "your question asks for" does. You cannot modify "n" records **and** return them  all at once. MongoDB has no method for this as it simply does not make sense. Either `.findAndModify()` one at a time, **or** `.update()` all at once. But with multiple, you **cannot** return the modified or orginal data. That is a seperate query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86683/discussion-between-roger-and-blakes-seven).

Comment: How do we do the same with Go's official MongoDB Driver?